# добрый вчер, ребята помогите решить задачу

Tags: javascript

изучаю колбэки, не могу решить задачу по одному из модулей, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, я видимо что-то упускаю, посмотрите пожалуйста, заранее благодарен за помощь!

```js
const pizzaPalace = {
  pizzas: ['Ультрасыр', 'Аль Копчино', 'Четыре нарезона'],
  order(pizzaName, onSuccess, onError) {
    if(this.pizzas.includes(pizzaName)){
      onSuccess(pizzaName)
        return  
    }
    onError(`В ассортименте нет пиццы с названием $ {pizzaName}`)
  },
};
// Пиши код выше этой строки
// Колбэк для onSuccess   
function makePizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Ваш заказ принят. Готовим пиццу ${pizzaName}.`;
}

// Колбэк для onError   
function onOrderError(error) {
  return `Ошибка! ${error}`;
}

// Вызовы метода с колбэками
pizzaPalace.order('Аль Копчино', makePizza, onOrderError);
pizzaPalace.order('Четыре нарезона', makePizza, onOrderError);   
pizzaPalace.order('Биг майк', makePizza, onOrderError);
pizzaPalace.order('Венская', makePizza, onOrderError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const pizzaPalace = {
  pizzas: ['Ультрасыр', 'Аль Копчино', 'Четыре нарезона'],
  order(pizzaName, onSuccess, onError) {
    if (this.pizzas.includes(pizzaName)) {
      return onSuccess(pizzaName);
    }
    return onError(`В ассортименте нет пиццы с названием ${pizzaName}`);
  }
}; 

function makePizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Ваш заказ принят. Готовим пиццу ${pizzaName}.`;
}

function onOrderError(error) {
  return `Ошибка! ${error}`;
}

console.log(pizzaPalace.order('Аль Копчино', makePizza, onOrderError));   
console.log(pizzaPalace.order('Четыре нарезона', makePizza, onOrderError));
console.log(pizzaPalace.order('Биг майк', makePizza, onOrderError));
console.log(pizzaPalace.order('Венская', makePizza, onOrderError));
```